# Create a Root CA self-signed certificate using the command line

Tags: certificate, public-key, pki

I have Microsoft Server 2019 offline Root CA

I want to renew the Root CA certificate, but I do not want it to be used immediately (as I want to push out the new Root CA certificate to key stores on clients ahead of using it to sign Issuing CA certificate/s).

if I renew on the Microsoft Certification Authority GUI tool (the standard one that is installed when you install the CA) the certificate immediately shows up in the configuration under the Properties section and is used to sign any new certificates.

The question is can I create from the command line (rather than the GUI) using guilt in command and tools like

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pki/new-selfsignedcertificate?view=windowsserver2022-ps

Whereby it is not active right away until I import it later?

Comment: Hi AUser, we're more about cryptographic algorithms and protocols rather than Microsoft implementation of a CA system. Would you mind if I migrate this to [su]?

Comment: Hi Maarten
Thanks for the input, what every you think will help me if fine

Comment: Are you trying to _renew_ the existing root CA certificate, or are you trying to create a new one? Renewing with the same subject + public key should not require any delay, but it sounds like you're trying to create a new CA with a new keypair instead?

Comment: Hello user1686

Thanks for taking the time to reply

I am 'renewing' the Root CA certificate. However I do not want to make it active right away and if I do this via the Windows Certification Authority GUI it will make it live right away. I want to create from the command line, then distribute the certificate manually so it can be install in key stores for computers not joined to AD. Then once they all have it I will make the new Root CA cert live, on the actual Root CA and then mint new Issuing CA certificates